# media query failing due to incorrect window size interpretation by webpage

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am creating a responsive web page, intended to be displayed on different screen sizes. I have included a **@media (min-width: 768px)**, but it seems that my page is somehow not able to correctly interpret window/screen size. I tried testing my webpage in Chrome, where enabling debug mode i can see the window size on topmost right corner in pixels. But running **window.innerWidth** in console is returning different value. It is returning correct value for all other websites. 
Any hints what could be wrong?

Comment: Please include an [mcve]. *Anything* could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error in your media query. You've to write

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
```

or you can write

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
```

If you need to understand how the media query works here's a small demo for you:

If the browser window is 600px or smaller, the background color will be lightblue in this css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
  body{
      background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Media type part of the media query is optional and defaults to `all` there is no syntax error in what OP gave.

Comment: Agreed but it's better to write media type part to clarify things, don't you think?

Comment: Nope. First neither `only screen` nor `screen` do the same as the implicit `all` OP used. Then, if there is no need for specificity don't include it. When you set `border: 1px solid` you won't declare explicitely all 3 `-color`, `-width`, `-style` of all four `border-top`, `border-right`, `border-bottom` and `border-left`. And moreover, that's obviously not OP's issue.